# Including CSS in Karma Tests using Webstorm Debugger

Tags: karma-runner, webstorm, karma-jasmine

I am using Backbone.js and RequireJs for a single page application.

When I run my karma tests, there is no css included.  When debugging it is difficult to know what is going on or why something is not working because the html elements are not styled like they are in the production appplication.

Is is possible to inlcude css in the karma tests while debugging using webstorm?

I have already tried including all css in the files array

```
files: [
    {pattern: 'app/css/*.css', included: false},
    ...
],
```

This is the css file that is included in index.html of the production application, there is nowhere in the karma configuration that I can find to add something like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - why would you want to have stylized html when doing tests? One case I see is that you might have shown/hidden elements (through css). Do you have any other cases?

Comment: My app was loading a bootstrap modal dialog, which did not display without the css.  My test was failing to find some elements that were generated from a json datasource. As soon as the app was styled I was able to identify the problem immediately.  It was caused by a previous select element that was not selected as it should have been.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked it out:

1. You need to add all your css to your karma.conf 'files' array.

   ```
   files: [
       {pattern: 'app/**/*.css', included: false},
       ...
   ],
   ```
2. Create a new module called `test_css.js`, the location of this file will depend on your folder structure. In here you need to programatically inject all your css files into your the current document.

   ```
   define(function(require) {
       "use strict";

       require('jquery');

       //Modify to suit your requirements
       $('body').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/base/app/css/styles.css" />');

   });
   ```
3. Include this module as part of the `deps` array in `test-main.js`

   ```
   requirejs.config({
       baseUrl: '/base/app/js',

       paths: {
           ...
           'test.css' : '../test_utils/test_css'
       },

       // ask Require.js to load these files (all our tests)
       deps: ['test.css'].concat(tests),

       // start test run, once Require.js is done
       callback: window.__karma__.start
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

jax answer was very helpful.

Additionally, for those not using *jQuery* but *d3.js*, your `test-css.js` can look like this:

```
define([
    'd3'
], function(d3) {
    "use strict";
    d3.select('body').append('link')
        .attr('rel', 'stylesheet')
        .attr('href', '/base/app/styles/mystyles.css');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a quite similar issue where my components were not appearing in Karma Test Runner by adding following to `files` key of `karma.conf.js`. I wanted Karma to automatically include the file so I set `included` to `true`.

```
.
.
.
files: [
  { pattern: 'node_modules/abc/abc.min.css', included:true, watched: false }
],
```

Upon doing this, I could then view my components in proper styling which made unit testing a lot faster and easier.